# android parsing error on tablet but not emulator

Tags: android, parsing, exception

I have this exception:

org.xml.saxParseException: Unexpected token (position TEXT@1:2...)

but it is caused only when running my .apk on a tablet pc. The same data when is parsed on the android emulator never causes this exception and works 100%. Any ideas?

Here's the code that throws the exception:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));
Document doc = db.parse(inputSource);
```

And here is a part from the file:

```
<Results> <Result title="08 07 2011"><Field title="blah blah" value="blah blah" /> </Result></Results>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default charset differs, maybe? Does the XML have a charset in it?

Comment: The locale I use in the emulator is greek. The locale in the tablet is english. Do you think that the greek characters written in the xml file could cause this?

Comment: Indeed, the file was created at a later time and it was encoded in ANSI. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I do think so. What encoding was the source data in? Does the string xmlData properly contain the Greek characters? Try tracing the position to the source string chars, check if it's a Greek one by any chance.

Comment: It was the encoding of the whole file not the greek characters. The other xml was created properly as utf-8. The problematic file was created as ansi, so that was the source of the problem.