# android utf-8 file parsing

Tags: android, parsing, exception, utf-8, sax

I have some `.xml` files that are encoded in `UTF-8`. But whenever I try to parse them on my tablet (idea pad, lenovo, android 3.1), I get the same error:

```
org.xml.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position: TEXT @1:2 in 
java.io.StringReader@40bdaef8).
```

These are the lines that throw the exception:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));
Document doc = db.parse(inputSource); // This line throws exception
```

Here is my input:

```
public String getFromFile(ASerializer aserializer) {
    String filename = aserializer.toLocalResource();
    String data = new String();
    try {
        InputStream stream = _context.getResources().getAssets().open(filename);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
        }
            stream.close();
            data = str.toString();
   }

           catch(Exception e) {
       }
       return data;
    }
```

XML File:

```
<Results>
    <Result title="08/07/2011">
        <Field title="Company one" value="030589674"/>
        <Field title="Company two" value="081357852"/>
        <Field title="Company three" value="093587125"/>
        <Field title="Company four" value="095608977"/>
    </Result>
    <Result title="11/07/2011">
        <Field title="Company one" value="030589674"/>
        <Field title="Company two" value="081357852"/>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

I don't want to convert them to `ANSI`, so is there any way to make the `db.parse()` work?

Comment: it would really make sense if you showed sample input with that

Comment: How did you read `xmlData`? I suspect that something went wrong there.

Comment: Editing my original answer with the method that reads the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870593/android-parsing-error-on-tablet-but-not-emulator

Comment: How is xmlData getting loaded? [String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) stores data as UTF-16, so presumably there's a problem with the initialisation, or the XML is corrupt - a sample would help.

Comment: Adding a part of the xml on my original post.

Comment: OT: it seems funny to me to use a StreamReader to read through a BufferedReader to read into a String, to parse with a SAX parser. I'm pretty sure the SAX parser can work directly on the stream/reader and much more efficiently

Comment: @sehe: more efficiently **and** more correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this line:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
```

You're reading from `stream` using the platform default encoding. That's *almost certainly* not what you want. You'd need to check the XML for for the actual encoding and the correct way to do that is [somewhat complicated](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-guessing).

Luckily, every sane XML parser (including the Java/Android one) can do that on its own. To make the XML parser do that, simply pass in the `stream` itself instead of trying to read it manually.

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(stream);
```

Comment: I have the file stream now. So, do I have to create a new Utf-8 String like data = new String(inputSource, "UTF-8"); ?

Comment: @coder: **No**! you **don't need a `String`**. Simply create an `InputSource` from the `stream` and pass that to the parser.

Comment: I'm adding a new method to my parsers with InputSource as argument.

Comment: I get a NullPointer Exception when I try to read the inputSource: Does this look ok? Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8"); inputSource = new InputSource(reader); stream.close();

Comment: 1. Don't close your stream until the parsing has completed. 2. **don't create a `Reader`!** `InputSource` has [a constructor that takes an `InputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource(java.io.InputStream))!

Comment: So, I'd rather return the stream and pass it as argument, parse it and then close the stream. Does this scenario sound better?

Comment: Yes, that's **exactly** what I was telling you to do in my post 1 hour ago.

Comment: I see, thanks. Well, my Managers were of general purpose. I load xmldata from http source as well, so I had to create a new method to do this and I was just doing so many changes I forgot the OP of yours. Thank you very much, in a few minutes I suppose it's going to be working.

Comment: @coder: no matter **where** you load XML from: trying to convert it to a `String` manually before parsing is a **bad idea**. If your input is (at some point) an `InputStream` then you should **always** pass *that `InputStream`* to the parser.

Comment: I see, then I can fix the http getter to send the stream as well. I tested it and it works, the only thing left it to make the greek characters appear correctly. So, I guess this is where the setEncode() fits somewhere.

Comment: @coder: if your XML is correct, then you **never** need to specify the encoding when parsing it: the XML parser must be able to figure it out. It *might* be necessary to specify some encoding later on, but that's unrelated to the XML parsing, then.

Comment: I just figured that. I have the same results as before. I'll need to remove the .setEncode() before parsing and and then find a way to fix the files or do something about it, after the fetching of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite likely using an XML file with a BOM mark (Byte Order Mark).

Either use an API that detects the encoding from the BOM

- [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream)

Alternatively, preprocess the file so that no BOM is present.

Comment: I have manually created the files with Notepad++ Encode: UTF-8 (Not BOM)

Answer (score 1):

Your java string is in an UTF-16 encoding be default. If you can't use InputStream as @Joachim Sauer suggested, then try this:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes()));
```