# Android - SAXParseException on InputStream from HTTP

Tags: android, xml, dom, sax

I am trying to parse an XML file which i get from a URL.

When parsing the XML from a local file from the Assets folder, there is no problem:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("xml-test.xml");  
Document dom = db.parse(is);
```

This works fine
But when i try to get the data from the web:

```
InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();  
Document dom = db.parse(in);
```

i get the SAX exception.

> specifically: "Unexpected Token (Position:TEXT   {"Quotes":  [{"Quo...@1:678 in java:io:InputStreamReader@41772e00)

the local file contains the same data as coming from the URL:

This is the URL:

http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/GB/GBP/en-GB/UK/anywhere/anytime/anytime?apiKey=prtl6749387986743898559646983194

Why is there a SAXException?

Thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10501540/1944666

Comment: but the xml i have is valid, as you can see in the link i provided. Also, when i "view source" and save to xml file, it works. so i dont think that the xml provided by the website is not valid.