# How to extract html from archive file generated by WebView？

Tags: html, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have the, exactly, same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868144/encoding-issue-on-kit-kat-android-when-saving-and-reading-a-webview) with saving and reading a webView.

Apparently, **webView.saveWebArchive(name)** returns a file with different format in Android 4.4. Therefore, I can't use [WebArchiveReader](https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader) any more.

Now the archive file looks like something below.

```
From: <Saved by WebKit>
Subject: Company Message[42]: NO EDA HTML Output
Date: Wed, 3 Dec 2013 14:36:47 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="----=_NextPart_6760_8467DEB7_081CADCA.490adfadsf92490"
 ------=_NextPart_000_8EafdasB7_081CADCA.4909adfas2490
 Content-Type: text/html
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
12-03 14:36:56.927: I/System.out(14711): Content-Location: http://foo.test.com/my_url.fex
 <html><head><meta charset=3D"ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Company Message[42]:  NO EDA HTML Output</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <hr><h3>
 Html Content 1
 </p></h3><hr>
 <pre><h5>
  Html Content 2
 </h5>
 </pre>
 <!--
 Html Content 3
 --></body></html>
 ------=_NextPart_000_8EB7_081CADCA.49092490--
```

It seems that the html content is already included in the archive file.

I can, however, read the Archive file to String by using the [given method](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ConvertInputStreamtoString.htm).
I wonder if it is possible to extract html part from the this file.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 4.4 WebView saves Web Archives in the MHTML format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML), which is different to the format used in previous versions of Android.

I've no experience with it myself, but maybe something like http://www.chilkatsoft.com/mht-features.asp may help you parse MHTML files.

Comment: Is this a tested solution?