# android 4.0.3 parse XML: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I try to parse an XML and get the following error, what could the problem be?

> I/System.out(8058): Wrong XML file structure: Unexpected token
>   (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@4113db88)

Thats the method I parse with

```
public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}
```

And thats the XML I try to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app>
    <Date Value="02.07.2012">
     </Date>
</app>
```

Comment: Try looking here, same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870593/android-parsing-error-on-tablet-but-not-emulator  it seems to be due to a difference in charset between your device and the xml

Comment: Thank you for you answer. How can I find out what the charset of the device is?

Comment: Please see the answer for the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254089/kxmlparser-throws-unexpected-token-exception-at-the-start-of-rss-pasing). In gist- there are some invisible byte marks that choke the pull parser

Comment: @BrunoBieri I am struggling with the exact same problem. How did you solve it? could you provide the solution in an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like it doesn't like the question mark. Can you make sure that you *save* the XML file with the correct encoding? (UTF-8)

Comment: The XML file was saved correctly with the UTF-8 encoding so I don't get it what the problem could be.

Comment: Can you print the `xml` string to make sure that it's read properly?

Comment: Yup, already done. The XML was read properly. The XML file has to be UTF-8 and the code have to handle with that.

Comment: Just curious - does it work if you remove the xml declaration tag? If not, what error does it report then?

Comment: did you actually found the solution to this ?

Comment: See my answer for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your java string is in an UTF-16 encoding be default. To create Document using string try this:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the project is already finished and I can't go back to change that.

Comment: yes, I understood. But maybe someone else will face with the same problem and it help him. Because I faced with this and found solution